# JSon.Net Json to entity

Tags: entity-framework, json.net

I have an entity, I setup the entity with the database you see below as an edmx file.
I also have a JSon file that I am pulling from edmunds.com 
I am using JSon.net and trying to parse the JSon object into the Entity and save the values of the Json to the Entity.

Every option I try to use it seems to blow up on me. 
Can anyone please provide me a decent example of how to accomplish this as it is driving me insane at this point.

```
{
   "dealerHolder":[
      {
         "id":"31711",
         "locationId":"3730",
         "address":{
            "street":"24825 US Hwy 19 N",
            "apartment":"",
            "city":"Clearwater",
            "stateCode":"FL",
            "stateName":"Florida",
            "county":"Pinellas",
            "country":"USA",
            "zipcode":"33763",
            "latitude":27.99785,
            "longitude":-82.729321
         },
         "name":"Countryside Ford of Clearwater",
         "logicalName":"CountrysideFordofClearwater",
         "type":"ROOFTOP",
         "make":"Ford",
         "operations":{
            "Wednesday":"8:30 AM-9:00 PM",
            "Tuesday":"8:30 AM-9:00 PM",
            "Thursday":"8:30 AM-9:00 PM",
            "Saturday":"8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
            "Friday":"8:30 AM-9:00 PM",
            "Monday":"8:30 AM-9:00 PM",
            "Sunday":"11:00 AM-5:00 PM"
         },
         "contactinfo":{
            "dealer_website":"http://www.clearwaterford.com/",
            "email_address":"",
            "phone":""
         },
         "publishDate":"2012-05-21",
         "active":true,
         "syncPublishDate":"2012-05-21"
      },
      {
         "id":"31673",
         "locationId":"3708",
         "address":{
            "street":"2525 34th St N",
            "apartment":"",
            "city":"Saint Petersburg",
            "stateCode":"FL",
            "stateName":"Florida",
            "county":"Pinellas",
            "country":"USA",
            "zipcode":"33713",
            "latitude":27.794484,
            "longitude":-82.679411
         },
         "name":"Autoway Ford of St Petersburg",
         "logicalName":"AutowayFordofStPetersburg",
         "type":"ROOFTOP",
         "make":"Ford",
         "operations":{
            "Wednesday":"08:30 AM-08:00 PM",
            "Tuesday":"08:30 AM-08:00 PM",
            "Thursday":"08:30 AM-08:00 PM",
            "Saturday":"09:00 AM-06:00 PM",
            "Friday":"08:30 AM-08:00 PM",
            "Monday":"08:30 AM-08:00 PM",
            "Sunday":"12:00 PM-05:00 PM"
         },
         "contactinfo":{
            "dealer_website":"http://www.autowayford.net/",
            "email_address":"",
            "phone":""
         },
         "publishDate":"2012-05-21",
         "active":true,
         "syncPublishDate":"2012-05-21"
      },
      {
         "id":"31636",
         "locationId":"3684",
         "address":{
            "street":"5815 N Dale Mabry Hwy",
            "apartment":"",
            "city":"Tampa",
            "stateCode":"FL",
            "stateName":"Florida",
            "county":"Hillsborough",
            "country":"USA",
            "zipcode":"33614",
            "latitude":28.00016,
            "longitude":-82.505206
         },
         "name":"Bill Currie Ford",
         "logicalName":"BillCurrieFord",
         "type":"ROOFTOP",
         "make":"Ford",
         "operations":{
            "Wednesday":"8:00 AM-9:00 PM",
            "Tuesday":"8:00 AM-9:00 PM",
            "Thursday":"8:00 AM-9:00 PM",
            "Saturday":"8:00 AM-8:00 PM",
            "Friday":"8:00 AM-9:00 PM",
            "Monday":"8:00 AM-9:00 PM",
            "Sunday":"11:00 AM-6:00 PM"
         },
         "contactinfo":{
            "dealer_website":"http://billcurriedirect.dealerconnection.com/",
            "email_address":"",
            "phone_areacode":"888",
            "phone_postfix":"1156",
            "phone_prefix":"255",
            "phone":"8882551156"
         },
         "publishDate":"2012-05-21",
         "active":true,
         "syncPublishDate":"2012-05-21"
      },
      {
         "id":"31723",
         "locationId":"3739",
         "address":{
            "street":"17556 US 19 N",
            "apartment":"",
            "city":"Clearwater",
            "stateCode":"FL",
            "stateName":"Florida",
            "county":"Pinellas",
            "country":"USA",
            "zipcode":"33764",
            "latitude":27.93164,
            "longitude":-82.730647
         },
         "name":"Walker Ford",
         "logicalName":"WalkerFord",
         "type":"ROOFTOP",
         "make":"Ford",
         "operations":{
            "Wednesday":"8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
            "Tuesday":"8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
            "Thursday":"8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
            "Saturday":"8:30 AM-6:00 PM",
            "Friday":"8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
            "Monday":"8:30 AM-8:00 PM",
            "Sunday":"11:30 AM-6:00 PM"
         },
         "contactinfo":{
            "dealer_website":"http://www.walkerford.com/",
            "email_address":"",
            "phone_areacode":"727",
            "phone_postfix":"3673",
            "phone_prefix":"535",
            "phone":"7275353673"
         },
         "publishDate":"2012-05-21",
         "active":true,
         "syncPublishDate":"2012-05-21"
      }
   ]
}
```

http://blog.redeyeproject.com/databasediagram.png

Here is the most recent Error I get 
Cannot deserialize JSON object (i.e. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1[DealerTentSaleMVC.Models.Operation]'.
The deserialized type should be a normal .NET type (i.e. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) or a dictionary type (i.e. Dictionary).
To force JSON objects to deserialize add the JsonObjectAttribute to the type. Path 'operations.Wednesday', line 22, position 19.

that error is happening with this code.

```
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string stws = wc.DownloadString(url);

        JToken root = JObject.Parse(stws);
        JToken dealerholder = root["dealerHolder"];
        DealerHolder convertedProducts = new DealerHolder();
        string dh = dealerholder.ToString().Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(dh, convertedProducts, new JsonSerializerSettings 
                                                            { 
                                                                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore

                                                            });
```

specifically it is happening on the last line there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build an object structure that reflects the JSON that you are trying to deserialize:

```
public class Result
{
    public DealerHolder[] DealerHolder { get; set; }
}

public class DealerHolder
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LogicalName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public Operations Operations { get; set; }
    public Contact Contactinfo { get; set; }
    public string PublishDate { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string SyncPublishDate { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Apartment { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StateCode { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

public class Operations
{
    public string Wednesday { get; set; }
    public string Tuesday { get; set; }
    public string Thursday { get; set; }
    public string Saturday { get; set; }
    public string Friday { get; set; }
    public string Monday { get; set; }
    public string Sunday { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string Dealer_website { get; set; }
    public string Email_address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
string json = .... go and fetch the JSON
Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
// do something with the result, like for example enumerating over the 
// dealer holders collection
```

Comment: Error gotten using your code
Cannot deserialize JSON object (i.e. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1[DealerTentSaleMVC.Models.Operation]'.
The deserialized type should be a normal .NET type (i.e. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) or a dictionary type (i.e. Dictionary<TKey, TValue>).
To force JSON objects to deserialize add the JsonObjectAttribute to the type. Path 'dealerHolder[0].operations.Wednesday', line 1, position 404.