# Windows Phone 7 - C# How to parse a multidimensional JsonArray?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, arrays

I'm trying to parse json data from the facebook c# sdk. The json data I'm trying to parse can be seen here at facebook: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBACQupPhpGCGi1Jce7eMfZCzt9GlpZBdhz3PlGCyHKNZB1r4FHgd9mgpm8W3g4Adpy9jJjFrsDuxcu3pE4uRT1lbIQjYKgZDZD

My code below will pop up a message box showing the first dimension of this json object, however, as you can see, there is a second dimension within each item which gives location information such as longitude and latitude. I'm struggling to find an example as to how one would get this with WP7 C# (most examples on the internet use libraries that aren't usable on WP7).

```
        fbClient.GetCompleted += (o, er) =>
        {
           if (er.Error == null)
           {
              var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)er.GetResultData();
              Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
              {
                  foreach (var item in (JsonArray)result["data"])
                  {
                     //message box for testing purposes
                     MessageBox.Show((string)((JsonObject)item)["name"]);
                  }
              });
           }
        });
```

Would someone be able to provide a quick example?

Thanks.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741374/json-net-json-to-entity it might give you a clue

Comment: Do you know which assembly's I would have to reference? This seems like a better approach.

Comment: Do you know which assembly's I would have to reference? I can't seem to get VS2010 to recognize JsonConvert.DeserializeObject for WP7, however, this link you've posted seems like a better approach.

Comment: I think that sample uses Json.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use with FacebookSDK it's not neccecary work with json directly.
Just cast JsonObjects to IDictionary and work with it like Dictionary:

```
//think better use IEnumerable<object>, because you don't really need JSON array
    foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<object>)result["data"])
                      {
                         var name = (item as IDictionary<string, object>)["name"];
                         //message box for testing purposes
                         MessageBox.Show(name);
                      }
```

So, you can work with `JsonArray` like `IEnumerable<object>` and with `JsonObject` like `IDictionary<string, object>`

Answer for you question:

```
var item1 = (IDictionary<string, object>)item;
var location = ((IDictionary<string, object>)(item1)["location"]);
var long = location["longitude"];
```

Or you can do it using JSON:

```
var location = ((JsonObject)((JsonObject)item)["location"]);
var long = location["longitude"];
```